# Spring webservices - is there better way to read HTTP headers than using annotation?

Tags: spring, rest, servlets, jax-rs, jax-ws

My web services on **my server look** like this. This is a working solution:

```
@GET
@Path("/path1")
Response getExample1(@HeaderParam("token") String token);

@GET
@Path("/path2")
Response getExample2(@HeaderParam("token") String token);
```

I have too many of these methods and the **jaxrs:client** has to include the variable token into every request

like so: `Response r = ws.getExample1(token);`

**the client has to do it even though the header variable token is ALREADY in the HTTP HEADER !**

I would like to client to just be able to make a call:

```
Response r = ws.getExample1();
```

And change my server-side to read the `token` header variable differently. I believe it must be possible but I don't know how. Can anybody share advice?

Thank you!

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation and version are you using?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I am using Apache CXF. I am sorry I should have mentioned that too.

Comment: I never really used CXF, but with Jersey I would inject a token object into the resource (the token would get build with the header extracted). I'm not sure how to do that with CXF. On the client side I would create a ClientRequestFilter to send the token on each request.